# How can I show phonetic (IPA) symbols on Android

Tags: android, unicode, encoding, webview, special-characters

I am trying to display phonetic symbols in a `WebView`, but so far I am only getting squares.

For instance, for the word "apostrophe", this should be displayed:

> əˈpåstrəfi

but all I am getting on the display is:

> □□påstr□fi

If it would help, I am getting the strings from an SQLite database. The string I retrieve has some HTML tags in it, so I use this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", 
     article, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString(), null);
```

where I have my CSS files in `/assets`. And the `article` variable contains some text enclosed in HTML tags.

Comment: @sh1ng: yes, but there seems to be a bug in 2.1.  I made a blog post about it here: http://bit.ly/id6qcJ

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved problem to display phonetic symbols in TextView. The problem is the default android fonts are not implement IPA symbols. I can advise to use ccs like this

```
@font-face {
  /* Regular */
  font-family: "ConstructiumRegular";
  src: url("http://openfontlibrary.org/content/RebeccaRGB/412/Constructium.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight:  400;
  font-style:   normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
}
```

In me case mentioned Constructium.ttf fits.

Answer (score 0):

If you pick up a unicode font like [Gentium](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Gentium_download), 
and you make sure you can change your font with a utility like [this](http://androidadvices.com/change-fonts-android-device-free-app/), you should be good to go. I don't have an Android, so there may be issues surrounding types of fonts that can be installed. You may need to check into that, or the font install utility that I've cited may not work well for you. ymmv